# posting an action from a partial view within a jquery dialog

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have an index page with a jquery tab loaded. Within one of the tabs I open a partial view company.ascx. Within that I have 2 `RenderActions`' One loads the company header and the other loads the branch information.

```
<%   Html.RenderAction("Compheader", "Home"); %>
<br />
<br />
<%  Html.RenderAction("BranchList", "Branch", new { Id = Request.QueryString[0], pdate = Request.QueryString[1] });   %>
```

Within `BranchList` I display a table of branches each of which has a delete button associated to it. There is also an add button on the branch list. Both these buttons open a jquery dialog that open partial views (acsx) within it. The dialogs have a submit post within them.

When the user clicks on submit on the insert/add or delete view I want to be able to refresh the BranchList action, which will get the new branchlist and display it.

Right now on post within the delete or insert I response redirect to the index page which refreshes the whole page. Can somebody tell me how I can accomplish this using `Html.BeginForm` and ajax posts in a clean way instead of the response redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing QueryString directly within your view and that means that you are not using any of the goodness of ASP.NET MVC framework. You should get these values in action method (using the matching parameter names as the QueryString variables in the action method's constructor) and then pass these values from action method to the view (using a view model or ViewData) so that you don't have to access QueryString directly inside the view.

Now coming to your question, I think you are doing it right. If you are getting the right behavior from your application, then you should not change the post-redirect behavior of the application.

You are posting the data from the partial views and then doing a redirect. This is a valid pattern, also known as GPG (Get, Post, Get) pattern. This is advantageous compared to simply sending the user to their "Posted" page as it avoids from letting the user post the same data twice in case they refresh the page.

Hope it helps.